# Issues accessing the local database (LocalDb)\v11.0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to install a php script locally on IIS.
I've gotten to the point where I need to fill in my database information.

I've connected to another database through visual studio, here's the connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TaskSubmitter.mdf;Initial Catalog=TaskSubmitter;Integrated Security=False; User Id=sa; Password=thepassword"
```

Now I've created a database named "pligg" for the php script.

The information I've filled in is the following:

**Database name:** pligg

**Database username:** sa

**Database password:** thepassword

**Database server:** (LocalDb)\v11.0

**Table prefix:** _pligg

However I get an error when trying to connect through the script.

The script is working fine so I'm sure I've done something wrong regarding the settings or the database.

Anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Yes, the code is wrong.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm very sure there are no errors with the script. It's Pligg so it definitely works.